# How to add "more" link in wordpress posts list using XML RPC Api

Tags: wordpress, api, xml-rpc

I am using wordpress xml-rpc API to add posts to my blogs, but I would like to have posts excerpts with "more" link in lists of posts. I checked that in database there is tag 
 in each post content which has excerpt, but if I put this tag in my article it does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an extra field, just add `<!--more-->` where you want the content to break.

You can even customize the "read more" message, like `<!--more But wait, there's more! -->`

Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More for more info